# Use params but i cant get value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, controller, parameters

I want to save in the method model those values but it doesnt save. I dont know if i've to use text_field_tag or something else.

View:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Nemónico' %>
    <%= f.text_field :nemo %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
n = params[:nemo]
Change.saveHist(current_user.email,n,DateTime.now.to_date)
```

Model:

```
def self.saveHist(session,nemo,date)
    h = DawHist.create(hsesion: session, hregnemo: nemo,hdate: date)
end
```

Comment: What is the content of the params hash from Rails's `development.log` ?

Comment: use create! instead of create to know the error. You might be having validation error

Comment: @architgupta i dit it and the error in log is 
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: nemo can't be blank):
  app/models/change.rb:8:in saveHit'
  app/controllers/registrers_controller.rb:52:in block in update'
  app/controllers/registrers_controller.rb:48:in update'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your posted params, you need to use the model's name (`Register` in your case I guess)

Therefore, when you use `params[:register][:nemo]`, you should be fine.

Comment: Work with `params[:register][nemo]`
Thanks!